# Is java heap space dictated by RAM or hard drive?

Tags: java, memory

I'm performing a huge calculation and I'm getting a "out of heap space" error. What I'm wondering is if Java does paging automatically, so that maybe my hard drive space can be used when performing this calculation? If it doesn't do it automatically, how do I turn this option on?

Comment: First thing that should be addressed is what calculation are you performing that is causing you to run out of heap space???

Answer (score 15):

The Java heap lives in RAM (ignoring virtual memory :). You can change the default initial heap size and maximum heap size with the [`-Xms` and `-Xmx` VM args](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/garbagecollection2/#4.2), respectively.

> The old generation, default heap size can be overridden by using the -Xms and -Xmx switches to specify the initial and maximum sizes respectively:
>
> ```
> java -Xms <initial size> -Xmx <maximum size> program
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> java -Xms128m -Xmx512m application
> ```

---

How much RAM does your machine have? Just what sort of a calculation is this that you think you need more heap than that?

Comment: BTW standard options `-mx` and `-ms` replaces `-Xmx` and `-Xms` in Java 6.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Where is that defined as standard?

Comment: Options `-mx` and `-ms` do not exist in OpenJDK 1.6.0_20.  See http://pastebin.me/e51511b66cf362a3fa139c93ab01fc2d.

Comment: I have OpenJDK 1.6.0_20 and it accepts `-ms` and `-mx` though it doesn't list them as options. This works fine `/usr/bin/java -ms512m -mx1g -version`

Answer (score 4):

The virtual memory manager of the operating system, not the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), decides when to eject memory pages and write them to the hard disk.

As earlier answers have mentioned, the JVM stores the heap space entirely in resident memory and most JVM implementations allow the user to specify the maximum heap space.  For example, the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) allows you to set the maximum heap size using the `-Xmx<size>` option.  Run `java -X` to see this and other non-standard OpenJDK command-line options.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the heap can determined however the JVM wants to. For most, it's via the -Xmx command line argument, with varying defaults. Chances are you want something like:

```
java -Xmx2048M foo.bar.MyProgram
```

Comment: Caution: Using numbers over 1280 on a 32bit windows OS can cause trouble.  If you see java crashing and creating hs_err* files, then decrease the max heap until they go away.

Comment: I've been able to use 1400 MB on Windows XP without any problems. This setting is used in our production Windows XP systems for years without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's determined by the operating system and by special flags.

```
$ java -X
...
    -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
    -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
    -Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
...
```