# Hazelcast memory storage

Tags: java, hazelcast

50 GB of data to be loaded to hazelcast maps . We have 100 GB RAM in our machine .
Configured 5 gb -XMX (heap size) .  While loading data to hazelcast maps , getting Out of memory exception .  Looked at the heap dumps ,  data is being written to heap instead of RAM . How to configure hazelcast to write data to RAM instead of heap ?

Comment: Heap is RAM

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276197/is-java-heap-space-dictated-by-ram-or-hard-drive?rq=1

You need to increase your Heap size

Comment: If there is no other process/application running on your server then try to utilize complete RAM for Heap storage. How many nodes are you running?

Comment: It is just single node setup

Comment: Single node is not really a use case for Hazelcast, since it is optimized for network operations (clusters)

Answer (score 3):

As @craigr8806 already mentioned the Java heap is in your RAM. I guess what you're looking for is the off-heap implementation HDMS (High Density Memory Store) which is an enterprise feature and not available in the opensource version. That way you would configure the HDMS available space to a max of, for example, 75GB and the map to use `in-memory-format` as `native`. That way data will not be stored in the GC collected Java heap but the HDMS.

As it is an enterprise feature, you need a different jar (hazelcast-enterprise.jar) and a license key. You can find a 30 days trial request form on our corporate website.

I hope that clarifies the situation :) If you're not talking about HDMS feel free to elaborate.

Comment: But do you think there will be any latency when writing and reading from off-heap compared to heap ?

Comment: There is a little bit more access latency as data need to be copied between offheap and onheap. Given the fact though that the GC has way less work, latency becomes more consistent and therefore mostly "less" than before.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal behaviour. Everything normaly goes into the heap. By setting -Xmx5 you have set a constraint on your maximum heap size to 5G. How are you going to put 50GB into 5GB ?

With respect of the off-heap  implementation I would first ask myself if the application is online(interactive) processing or offline and how much latency you realy can tolerate. In case you have an offline processing the latency is not important in which case haveing a "stop the world event" would not be that big of an issue.